# C# MEF: Threadsafe Export

Tags: c#, mef

Suppose I have a `CarSystem` class, which has a collection of `CarParts` objects in it. Now I wish to write a stereo plugin to the system, and I wish the format of all plugins to be:

```
public interface ICarPluginMetaData
{
  string Name {get;}
  string Description {get;}
  int Status {get; set;}
}

public interface ICarPlugin
{
  void int setStatus(int newStatus);
}

[Export(typeof(ICarPlugin))]
[ExportMetaData("Name", "Stereo")]
[ExportMetaData("Description","Plays music")]
[ExportMetaData("Status", 0)]
public class StereoPlugin : ICarPlugin
{
  [ICarPluginImport("FrontSpeakers")]
  public CarPart myFrontSpeakersPointer;

  [ICarPluginImport("RearSpeakers")]
  public CarPart myRearSpeakersPointer;

  [ICarPluginImport("subwoofer")]
  public CarPart mysubwooferPointer;

  [Export]
  public void setStatus(int newStatus)
  {
    Status = newStatus;
  }
}
```

Now in my CarSystem class, I define exports, however the default behavior is to create 1 static object, and hand it to all those importing it; how would I be able to do the following:

```
[ExportAsThreadsafe]
public CarPart FrontSpeakers

[ExportAsThreadsafe]
public CarPart RearSpeakers

[ExportAsThreadsafe]
public CarPart Subwoofer

[ExportAsThreadsafe]
public CarPart DashLights
```

so that when I create a second plugin, running on a separate thread, I get a threadsafe connection to the actual object for all plugins?

Comment: "Thread-safe connection to object"? There is absolutely no golden hammer for threading - especially one reliable enough for Microsoft to provide as part of MEF. Using `[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]` would give each object a unique instance (which is 'more' thread safe if used correctly). This is going to sound rude - but it's honestly good avice: go and make an effort to learn why this won't work and you will understand enough about threading to actually use it. Simple answer - `[Import]` the objects and `lock` them as always.

Comment: As explicit as proposing a solution, and then suggesting I learn more why "this" wont work is, I understand the problems of making something threadsafe; my question, I suppose, didn't fully illuminate my proposed algorithm.

Comment: There's a collection of objects. Each object has a ConcurrencyQueue (this is already threadsafe) associated with it. When a plugin requests access to the object, it's given a copy of the object which dumps messages directly into the queue. At my leisure, I process all requests currently in the queue. The objects given to plugins are/can be in separate threads, however the queue and everything else in the CarSystem are running in one. In this manner I intend to circumvention any thread conflicts. My question was: how can I create a simple custom export provider which would allow me to do this.

Comment: If I understand your explanation correctly `[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]` will do what you want it to do - I have never written an export provider so you will possibly need to update the question with this information.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that <code>[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]</code> only works with classes, not fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I've ended up doing (in pseudocode):

```
Foreach plugin dynamically loaded
{
    //Via reflection
    Foreach field in the plugin
    {
        See if the field has an attribute attached
        Find the field who's name is the same as it's attribute's name
        {
            Using some lookup method, find the object in the CarSystem
            collection who's name is the same as the attribute name.
            create a concurrencyQueue using proxy object
            call field.SetValue(pluginObject, new Proxy Object) //Reflection call
        }
    }
}
```

I basically said, "screw MEF doing this automatically" and did it myself, using Reflection and custom Attributes. I used MEF to do one way messaging, but for plugin's that needed to alter objects in the CarSystem I used my custom "MEF" style.

Answer (score 1):

One way to provide thread safety in MEF is to perform a separate independent MEF composition in each thread. Everything constructed in that composition is then local to that thread. Any cross-thread access is under your control and you can use normal thread safety techniques.

I'm not clear on whether you want to load multiple stereo plugins and have them available to / bound to one global CarSystem, or if you are simply talking about having multiple CarSystems in different threads, independent of each other. You can do the latter by MEF composing the CarSystem with a particular stereo plugin inside of a thread.

Comment: What I am going for is this: One CarSystem which has a collection of objects. All plugins wishing to access the CarSystem collection can do so, in a threadsafe manner (as each plugin may be a separate thread)

Comment: @BenjaminKiefer MEF exports aren't going to do that for you. Your best bet is to make the CarSystem collection one of the new threadsafe collections (.net 4.0) and export the collection object itself, or export a CarSystem wrapper object with access methods that acquire locks around an internal private collection.  The latter will be tricky if enumerating the internal list is a frequent activity. I'd lean towards exporting a prebaked thread-safe collection.

Comment: @dthrope the idea of this whole thing is that the person writing the plugin is not me, and I don't want them knowing how the exact architecture of my object collection is structured. In that way, I can restructure without having to rebuild their code. I also want a regular kid off the street to be able to fairly easily understand how to write a plugin for my system.

Comment: The plugin writer doesn't need to know the structure of your CarSystem if you implement your CarSystem wrapper to export its methods for plugins to bind to. The wrapper is a bridge between the default MEF binding and your internal thread safety code.